# What is actually "exclusive of tax" mean?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, accounting

Recently I got an offer for work from a U.S. company as an independent contractor, and in the contract it says "All amounts payable pursuant to this agreement are exclusive of taxes." I am quite unsure about what this actually means. Does this mean the company will pay the tax and will not cut it from the amount offered? or do I have to pay the tax myself from my compensation in which the company agreed to provide?

I will be working outside the U.S., in Dubai.

Comment: Where is the job, and where are you?

Comment: @keshlam the job offer is from US

Comment: I read it to mean, the number offered is gross, you are responsible for your taxes.

Comment: "Exclusive of taxes" - What an odd way to say it. In the U.S., I'm sure the salary number they are giving you is before taxes, but the words they chose are ambiguous, if not wrong.

Comment: @benmiller: I think what it really means is "Our HR department desperately needs to hire someone who can write."

Comment: Hi, how could it be a remote position job. Like an offer from US and the employer is going to work for them remotely from another country like Dubai?. How does this Tax statement apply then?

Comment: Are you doing the work inside the U.S., or outside? Are you going to be an employee for this company, or a contractor? If you are a contractor, then essentially, you are your own employer (self-employed).

Comment: Hi @BenMiller yes it's going to a remote position job, self employed(I am the CTR in contract), I am going to work from Dubai and employer is located in USA. Can you tell me then how the tax applies in that case?

Comment: In the U.S., words like "salary" and "job offer" imply a direct employee relationship.

Comment: @ben That's assuming the ad was written by someone using the US conventions. If it was written by someone in Dubai, all bets are off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are an independent contractor, the company you are doing this job for will not be paying or withholding any tax. It is your responsibility to pay any taxes that are due.

Unless you are a U.S. Citizen, if you are not living in the U.S. when you perform this work, you won't have any tax liability for the U.S.  But you will need to make sure that any tax due to the U.A.E. or whatever country you are a citizen of is paid.

Comment: Excellent Ben, that clarified by doubt. I apologize for bad english.

Answer (score 3):

In the US,  it would be almost certain that they are quoting the gross pay before income taxes have been subtracted out.

But the phrase they have used is ambiguous, so no matter where this is, I think the only way to be sure is to ask them.

Comment: Hi, how could it be a remote position job. Like an offer from US and the employer is going to work for them remotely from another country like Dubai?. How does this Tax statement apply then?

Answer (score 0):

It can be interpreted to mean several things at once:

- That number is your gross pay before taxes.
- They will not be responsible for withholding taxes.
- You will have to pay for taxes on your own from that amount.

You may have additional information that makes clear the correct interpretation, but best to ask.

Comment: Hi, how could it be a remote position job. Like an offer from US and the employer is going to work for them remotely from another country like Dubai?. How does this Tax statement apply then?